# Simultaneous outgoing connections limit with iptables not working

Tags: networking, iptables, rate-limiting

I run a website that technically acts as a proxy to another website (I make HTTP requests to it), and I needed to make sure not too many simultaneous connections were made, I thus limited it to 29 simultaneous connections with iptables:

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m connlimit --connlimit-above 29 -j REJECT`

It’s the only rule I use, besides the default `INPUT ACCEPT` / `FORWARD ACCEPT` / `OUTPUT ACCEPT`.

I tested that rule against another server of mine, and I was seeing only a maximum of 29 connections in iptables on that other server.

Yet, the other website which I’m proxying reported to me that they saw 1499 simultaneous connections at peak. Wow. This made their website unstable and they had to ban my server’s IP, which they said got their website back to stability.

Note: This site has their DNS point to two IPs, but 1499 is much greater than 29 × 2.

I’m running Debian stable, nginx and php, and the connections are made through PHP’s cURL functions. I don’t reuse connections because PHP makes that impossible with its cURL implementation.

Question: **How is this possible? Is this possible at all?** Any idea?

The best theory I have (which seems impossible to me, unless they would be doing some really funky stuff) is that somehow the requests are closed on my server but not on theirs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking your hunch is on the right track.  The connection is only in state NEW until it receives the ACK from the other end.  You are saying, "only allow 29 SYNs without ACKs out of port 80 at a time."   So your rule is limiting the number of PENDING connections to 29, but once established, there is no limit.

If the other side is sending back ACKs in a timely fashion, then those connections which have received them are no longer in state "NEW", and therefore don't count against the limit.

It might be worthwhile to test by dropping the --state filter, and adding the destination.  So that way you are rate limiting all connections to the $DESTINATION_SERVER:$DESTINATION_PORT regardless of state.  This could confirm your hunch.